# Two questions regarding mathematical writing

Tags: article-writing

I am a German mathematics student. I have two questions:

First question: When writing several equivalent equations, we usually write this as:

$x^2 = 4$

$\Leftrightarrow x = \pm 2$

I have never seen this in English, i.e. the usage of $\Leftrightarrow$ to indicate equivalence in a sequence of equations. Is it considered bad style? How would you write this?

Second question: In German, we often declare variables within a sentence similar to:

"The output $x$ depends on the time of default $t$ and on the sum $S$ of all payments made prior to $t$."

Is this correct in English? I am not sure whether or not I have seen this before. If not, what would be an alternative formulation?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: For your statement 1, this would be acceptable, in English, for lectures or work on a board.  In written English, people are encouraged to use fewer symbols; for example, the $\Leftrightarrow$ might be avoided.  The first statement might be written as "$x^2=4$ is equivalent to $x\in\{-2,2\}$."

Comment: The style of your second statement is common in English mathematics.

Comment: There is an \iff command in LaTeX, it means "if and only if" (which is equivalence). So the symbol exists and means the same.

Comment: @mvw: A nicer version is `\Leftrightarrow`. I never understood why `\iff` was made so long.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: You should transfer your comments into an answer. =)

Comment: Some people just write " $x^2=4$ iff $x=\pm 2$ ".

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement would be acceptable, in English, for lectures or for work on a board.  In written English, people are encouraged to use fewer symbols; for example the $\Leftrightarrow$ might be avoided.  Someone might write this statement as "$x^2=4$ is equivalent to $x\in\{-2,2\}$."

Note that there are many alternatives to the phrase "is equivalent to" which would be acceptable, but few are shorter.

The style of your second statement is common in English mathematics.

Note that this is for *American* English.  I'll leave other forms to native speakers in those languages.